# Prove that composition of two linear mappings is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening,

I have to solve this task and would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Let $V, W, Z$ be vector spaces.

(a) Let $ T \in\mathscr L(Z, V)$, where $\mathscr L$ is a homomorphism. I have to prove that $$\Phi : \mathscr L(V, W) \to \mathscr L(Z, W), \Phi(L) = L \circ T$$

My approach would be to prove that additivity and homogeneity are fulfilled. But I'm not sure how do that exactly.

Let L1 and L2 be  $\in$ $\mathscr L$(V, W). And let z be $\in$ Z.

$\Phi$((L1+L2)(z)) = (L1 + L2) $\circ$ T(z) = (L1+L2)(T(z)) = L1(T(z)) + L2(T(z)) = $\Phi$(L1(z)) + $\Phi$(L2(z)).

And homogeneity:

Let $\lambda$$\in$ $\mathbb R$.

$\Phi$($\lambda$L(z)) = ($\lambda$L) $\circ$ T(z) = $\lambda$L(T(z) = $\lambda$ * $\Phi$(L(z)).

In (b) I would have to prove the following:
Let T $\in$ $\mathscr L$(W, Z), where $\mathscr L$ is a homomorphism.
$\Phi$ : $\mathscr L$(V, W) $\to$ $\mathscr L$(V, Z), $\Phi$(L) = T $\circ$ L is linear.

Thank you very much! I am grateful for any solutions or hints.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want here. Your proofs of additivity and homogeneity of $\Phi$ seem fine to me. Did you want us to verify/critique them?

Comment: In (a): "I have to prove that $\Phi$: [specification]" ... does what?  What are you trying to prove about $\Phi$?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have to prove that $\Phi$ is linear. And yes, I am wondering whether the proof is valid.